# SilverStripe DropdownField default for boolean value

Tags: php, silverstripe

I can't set a default value for a DropdownField

```
DropdownField::create('Foo', 'Foo', array(true => 'Yes', false => 'No'), $value = true);
```

When creating a new page, the field shows *No* `false => 'No'`. Is it because the $db value for `Foo` is set to *Null* by default?

Or is it because the *Default* parameter for `DropdownField` should be a string, whereas here it's a boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the defaults with one of those.

```
private static $defaults = [
  'Foo' => true
];
```

or if you want to have a more dynamic way

```
public function populateDefaults() {
  parent::populateDefaults();

  $this->Foo = true;
}
```

Comment: The first method ($defaults) works, still I don't understand what the point is of setting a default to `DropdownField` while it clearly follows the initial `$db` value

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
DropdownField::create('Foo', 'Foo', array(true => 'Yes', false => 'No'), 0);
```

The issue you were having is that you were passing `false`. I think the code was interpreting that `false` as no default value being set. Similar as if you passed `null`. Any value other than `null` or `false` should work.